# AWS -> S3 -> Fine Uploader, fails region in callback false

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I wrote a server like this: [Link](https://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser)

My upload script looks like (onpage script):

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById("fineUploader"),
        request: {
            endpoint: "bucket.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
            accessKey: "accesskey",
        },
        signature: {
            version: 4,
            region: "eu-central-1",
            endpoint: "https:127.0.0.1:8000/s3handler"
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: false
        },
        chunking: {
            enabled: true
        },
        paste: {
            targetElement: document,
            promptForName: true
        }
    });
```

I get the credentials, after upload I get the error message:

```
the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-central-1'
```

At the Node Server is the x-amz-credential returns also at region us-east

```
vaildkey/vailduntil/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
```

But I added already at the client (see first code) region to the signature. 
Also I added to the expectedHostname the same link as endpoint at the top,
and start the server with  `aws.config.region='eu-central-1';`

What did I make wrong that the region does not changes?

Comment: As workaround, I created a second bucket in region us-east-1, after this change, it works. But what is the bug?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Fine Uploader docs](https://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options-s3.html#objectProperties), you'll want to set a top-level property called `objectProperties` containing your region (it defaults to `us-east-1`, which is why creating your bucket in that region works).

Your uploader script would thus look like this:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById("fineUploader"),
    objectProperties: {
        region: "eu-central-1"
    },
    request: {
        endpoint: "bucket.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
        accessKey: "accesskey",
    },
    signature: {
        version: 4,
        endpoint: "https:127.0.0.1:8000/s3handler"
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: false
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    paste: {
        targetElement: document,
        promptForName: true
    }
});
```